# what to write test cases for Site.ChangePassword();

Tags: force.com

```
PageReference pf = Site.changePassword(newPassword, verifyNewPassword, oldPassword);
```

This pf object always return null and i am unable to cover the lines after this line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Test.isRunningTest()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_isRunningTest) to simulate anything you want after the call during test execution.

E.g.

```
PageReference pf = Site.changePassword(newPassword, verifyNewPassword, oldPassword);
if(Test.isRunningTest()) {
    pf = new PageReference('http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/');
}
// Remaining lines that depend on the PageReference.
```